# Access header sent from nginx to apahce inside htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, http-headers

I have a Nginx server listening to port 80/443 and passing all the .php requests to Apache

As part of the proxy I've added several headers that I later use in my PHP scripts:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

When I access the headers throw php (e.g. `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]`) everything works just fine.
But - when I try to access the exact same headers through mod_rewrite in my `.htaccess` file I get empty string instead.

This is how my `.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR} !(^127\.0\.0\.1$)
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

I'd really appreciate your help,

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

> Other things you should be aware of:
>
> ...
>
> 4.%{HTTP:header}, where header can be any HTTP MIME-header name, can always be used to obtain the value of a header sent in the HTTP request. Example: %{HTTP:Proxy-Connection} is the value of the HTTP header ``Proxy-Connection:''.

So try %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For}